# Unable to connect with RDS SQL Server using PyODBC & AWS Lambda

Tags: python, sql-server, aws-lambda, timeout, pyodbc

I’ve written the following python script where I’m trying to connect with a RDS SQL Server using PyODBC-

```
import pyodbc

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        # Establishing a connection with Database
        connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=RDS-Server-URL-Here;DATABASE=DB-Name-Here;UID=USER-Here;PWD=Password-Here")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception Details:")
        print(e)
```

*After running this script on AWS Lambda (Python 3.7 Environment), getting following **error**-*

('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Attached the following two policies to AWS Lambda-

•   AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
•   AmazonRDSFullAccess

Since PyODBC is an external library, I’ve added it into the Lambda Layers and was successfully able to import the library.
Downloaded the necessary required libraries from following repo-
https://github.com/kuharan/Lambda-Layers/blob/master/3.7/pyodbc-layer.zip

Referring to the following article-
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/aws-lambda-python-ms-sql-server-the-easy-way-e7667d371cc5

There are couple of solutions mentioned in the questions facing similar issue-

- Try Using IP of Server
- Adding Port Number
- Adding Timeout

I’ve tried all of these but none of the solution is working.

Any solution will be appreciated a lot. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Security groups? Have a read through [Connecting to a DB instance running the Microsoft SQL Server database engine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Security Groups are configured correctly as I'm able to SSMS in RDS from another EC2 instance and there are other services as well which can communicate with the RDS without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved, problem was not with the python script or PyODBC.
The root cause of the problem was the network connectivity. My Lambda function was not present inside the VPC in which the RDS was created.

After attaching the Lambda function to the same VPC, the network connectivity was established and the python script ran successfully without any error.